# cleaner alternative for conditional typedef using templates

Tags: c++, templates

While playing around with some templates, to remove some macros in my code, I got to the following code,

```
typedef std::conditional<sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*),
    int,
    std::conditional<sizeof(long int) == sizeof(void*),
        long int,
        std::enable_if<sizeof(long long int) == sizeof(void*), long long int>::type
    >::type
>::type Int;
typedef std::conditional<sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(Int),
    unsigned int,
    std::conditional<sizeof(unsigned long int) == sizeof(Int),
        unsigned long int,
        std::enable_if<sizeof(unsigned long long int) == sizeof(Int), unsigned long long int>::type
    >::type
>::type UInt;
```

while trying to replace,

```
#if sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)
    typedef int Int;
    typedef unsigned int UInt;
#elif sizeof(long int) == sizeof(void*)
    typedef long int Int;
    typedef unsigned long int UInt;
#elif sizeof(long long int) == sizeof(void*)
    typedef long long int Int;
    typedef unsigned long long int UInt;
#else
    #error
#endif
```

Can you think of a cleaner and shorter alternative using templates? or is it just a bad idea to use templates to replace every possible macros.

Btw, that code is used for passing integer values to some C functions that only accept `void*`, with minimal overhead.

Comment: I don't know what `enable_if` is doing there?

Comment: Can you give us an example to show how it is used in your C functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an alias would help you:

```
using Int  = best<int,best<long int,long long>>;

using UInt = best<unsigned int,best<unsigned long int,unsigned long long int>>;
```

where `best` is a template alias, defined as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
using best = typename std::conditional<sizeof(T)==sizeof(void*),T,U>::type;
```

Note that I'm not sure if that solves your problem, but if your complain is about lengthy templates, then maybe the above technique gives you some  idea as to how to make it a bit shorter — *and cleaner*.

You could use `_t` version if you have C++14:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
using best = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T)==sizeof(void*),T,U>;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular task, you seem to want (roughly):

```
typedef intptr_t Int;
typedef uintptr_t UInt;
```

Comment: This is good but I'm going to go a step further and suggest to use the original `foo-ptr_t` types directly rather than hiding them behind a typedef.

Comment: @MarkB: I did consider that, but if he has a significant body of code that already uses his `Int`/`UInt` types, that might involve quite a bit of extra work for little real benefit.